# Android 5.1.1 no "move to SD Card" option

Tags: sd-card, 5.1-lollipop

Just bought a nice 9" Android with 8GB storage.  Put in a 32 GB SD card.  It shows up under storage.  When I select Apps then pick an app, there is no option to move it to the SD card like I had under Kit Kat on another unit.  It does show the Clear Cache and Clear Data options.

I just erased the SD card and it still just shows up as empty, under Storage.  The internal 8 GB is starting to fill up so I really need to use the SD card.

Q:  How can I move apps to the SD card when the option is not there under App info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the paid version of [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to move the majority of apps to the SD card, if your device is rooted.

(no financial stake in Titanium Backup, just a satisfied user)

Comment: @SDsolar "philosophically disinclined to pay for software"... You either pay for it, the company steals your data to cover the cost, or the poor independent guy just goes out of business.

Comment: I have been an independent developer for years, and trust me, if people like the software and want the Pro features they will pay for it.  But there is no need to pay for most software.  Shareware is what launched the world of software.  People got rich from simple donations because their software was good.  But I will not pay a penny until I know it works, like I have with Acronis True Image.

Answer (score 1):

First I need you to tell me that you only are able to move a few apps. Often apps which include Google Play Services need to be in internal storage.

Check out first if any of your apps are able to be moved using the system (often games or apps like wikipedia). If not, just go to the Google Play Store and get an app which do that for you.

Comment: My old Kit Kat phone has a move option, but the more modern 5.0 does not.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 5 and older, not all apps can be moved to the SD card. If you look in the"SD card" tab of the apps settings, you can look only at the ones that can be moved. In Android 6 the option to add SD cards as internal storage was added. See if you can upgrade to Android 6.

Comment: EF Explorer lets me move most of the data, which is good enough.  Too bad they removed that option, though.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose to move apps to the SD card is usually to save space on the limited internal storage.

For all the apps that let the user choose the storage folder (in my case Podcast Player) this is an effective solution:
[www.beyondpod.com/Moving-podcasts-to-external-SD-Card](http://www.beyondpod.com/forum/showthread.php?3880-Moving-podcasts-to-external-SD-Card&s=e0e709bac5394140759fce550cb95c12&p=16013&viewfull=1#post16013)

The solution is this:

> EVERY app can write to its own private folder (and subfolders thereof) on SD >cards on KitKat (and Lollipop). It's just a matter of knowing what the folder >should be called. It will be
>   "sdcard path"/Android/data/"app ID"
>   For BeyondPod it's "sdcard"/Android/data/mobi.beyondpod/files
>
> You'll need your phone manufacturer's File Manager app to create this folder 
>   (since only a system app can write to any arbitrary place on an SD card). If your device didn't come with a pre-installed File Manager, you'll have to >create the folder on a PC. But once it exists, the app's "owner" will be able to write to it and any subfolder within it.

I found the right "app ID" by just looking at the default storage path.